# Sumar máximas rachas de resultados en apuestas ganadas, perdidas o empatadas

Tags: php, mysqli, algoritmos

Tengo un sistema de pronósticos para apuestas, consiste en acertar, fallar o empatar, los datos los almaceno en una tabla con el campo "resultado" en MySQL con el siguiente formato:

Donde 0 = fallar, 1 = ganar y 2 = empatar

```
id | resultado 
---------------
1  | 0
2  | 0
3  | 0
4  | 1
5  | 1
6  | 1
7  | 1
8  | 1
9  | 0
10 | 0
11 | 1
12 | 1
13 | 2
14 | 2
15 | 1
...
```

Necesito obtener las máximas rachas de cada resultado, en el ejemplo se ganaron 5 máximas consecutivas, se perdieron 3 máximas consecutivas y se empataron 2 máximas consecutivas.

Logré hacer algo en PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getSignals , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $result = $row['forex_pair_signals_result'];

        if($result == 1)
            $rachaITM++;

        if($result == 0)
            $rachaOTM++;

        if($result == 2)
            $rachaATM++;
    }
```

Pero solo obtengo los totales de cada una.

¿Cómo es posible obtener esos datos?

Gracias

Comment: que tal si defines tu array de `$datos =["OTM","ITM","ATM"]` y `$racha[$dato[$result]] += 1 `

Comment: @JackNavaRow no quiere obtener los totales, sino los máximos consecutivos.

Comment: @the-breaker entonces tengo que hacer una variacion a lo comentado  validando la racha previa

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes resolver concatenando todos los valores de un array en una cadena que te quedaría así:

```
00111110011221
```

Luego en el caso de las ganadas (1) conviertes todos los 0 y 2 en '_' con `str_replace()`:

```
__11111__11__1
```

luego los conviertes en un array de cadenas con `array_filter(explode('_', $cadena))`:

```
['11111', '11', '1']
```

luego hallas los tamaños de cada cadena con `$lengths = array_map('strlen', $cadenas);`:

```
[5,2,1]
```

y luego hallas el máximo con:

```
$rachaOTM = max($lengths);
```

Realizas lo mismo para empate y falla. El código luego te queda así:

```
<?php 

$result='';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getSignals , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $result.= $row['forex_pair_signals_result'];
    }

//en el ejemplo $result tendría el valor    
//$result='00111110011221';

$res2=str_replace([1,2], '_', $result);
$res2=array_filter(explode('_', $res2));
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $res2);
$rachaITM = max($lengths);

$res2=str_replace([0,2], '_', $result);
$res2=array_filter(explode('_', $res2));
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $res2);
$rachaOTM = max($lengths);

$res2=str_replace([0,1], '_', $result);
$res2=array_filter(explode('_', $res2));
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $res2);
$rachaATM = max($lengths);

echo "Perdidas $rachaITM, ganadas $rachaOTM, empates $rachaATM";

 ?>
```

y los resultados serán:

> Perdidas 2, Ganadas 5 empates 2

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias tu respuesta me ayudó mucho, de verdad gracias :)

Comment: de nada @damianventura si no es mucha molestia puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar arrays y comparar cada numero con el numero anterior.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
$array = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,1,1];
$rachaITM = [0];
$rachaOTM = [0];
$rachaATM = [0];
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getSignals , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $result = $row['forex_pair_signals_result'];
        if($i==0){    

          if($result == 1)
            $rachaITM[0]++;

          if($result == 0)
            $rachaOTM[0]++;

          if($result == 2)
              $rachaATM[0]++;
        } elseif ($result == $array[$i-1]) {
            if($result == 1)
              $rachaITM[count($rachaITM)-1]++;

            if($result == 0)
              $rachaOTM[count($rachaOTM)-1]++;

            if($result == 2)
              $rachaATM[count($rachaATM)-1]++;
        } else {
            if($result == 1)
              $rachaITM[] = 1;

            if($result == 0)
              $rachaOTM[] = 1;

            if($result == 2)
              $rachaATM[] = 1;
        }
        $i++;
    }

echo max($rachaITM) . "\n";
echo max($rachaOTM) . "\n";
echo max($rachaATM) . "\n";
?>
```